# code deploy from springloops

Tags: amazon-web-services, svn, springloops

I am using springloops repo(SVN) for my projects.I need to deploy my repo directly from springloops to ec2 using code deploy in aws.Now I am using codecommit for this purpose,but it is time consuming process and also not userfriendly as SVN